# Is there a way to change the 15-minute edit rule for comments on a Ning site?

Tags: ning

On a Ning community site, if you post a comment it will say "you have 15 minutes to edit this comment" and then it begins to count down. But if you come back a day later and realize you wrote:

> I do not support that...

but you MEANT to write

> I do now support that...

you sit there with technical handcuffs on in front of your sentence that means the exact opposite of what you meant, with no way to change it. This limitation contributes to inaccuracies, typos, and unclear language throughout the site, so there must be a way to change this.

**Apparently we can edit discussions a day later, is there a way to allow users to edit comments indefinitely as well?**

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change this - it is a default setting and cannot be changed.  Only moderators can change/delete comments.

[Source Article](http://creators.ning.com/forum/topics/15-minute-limit-to-edit)